# Kate editor cannot open/save files

Tags: kate

I installed Kate 19.08.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Most menus seem to work well, but I cannot open/save files. File -> Open does nothing. Does anyone know how to solve this?

When opening kate in the terminal, it gives the following error message multiple times:

```
An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; 
type=\"method_call\", 
sender=\":1.320\" (uid=1001 pid=16686 
comm=\"kate \" 
label=\"snap.kate.kate (enforce)\") 
interface=\"org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable\" 
member=\"Introspect\" 
error name=\"(unset)\" 
requested_reply=\"0\" 
destination=\"org.freedesktop.UDisks2\" (uid=0 pid=1203 comm=\"/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd \" 
label=\"unconfined\")
```

Comment: What happens if you enter `kate /path/to/edited/file` in a terminal?

Comment: From where did you get Kate 19.08.0? The version of Kate in 18.04 is 17.12.3.

Comment: I installed it via snap: https://snapcraft.io/install/kate/ubuntu

Comment: @xenoid Entering kate /path/to/edited/file opens the file, but File->Open and File->Save still do nothing, so, I cannot save it after editing.

Comment: Perhaps this helps. When opening kate in terminal, it gives the following error message multiple times:

 "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.320\" (uid=1001 pid=16686 comm=\"kate \" label=\"snap.kate.kate (enforce)\") interface=\"org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable\" member=\"Introspect\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"org.freedesktop.UDisks2\" (uid=0 pid=1203 comm=\"/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd \" label=\"unconfined\")"

Comment: @Gumum Can you add that error to the end of your question between two groups of three backtick's on a separate line for better readability. These `\`\`\`` on a separate line before and after the error messages. Thanks.